# Get height and width of a element after trasforming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the size of an **HTML element** after **transforming/zooming** using **webkit** or any other methods.

After zoomed in, the element takes more pixels that it took before transformation.

I tried `.height() .width() .offsetHeight()  .clientHeight()` all of them just returns same values after transforming the element.

Is there a way to get actual width and height of a element after transforming?

Comment: with transforming/zooming, do you mean the normal zoom functions of your browser 'strg + mousewheel' or CSS transforming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get effective styles on your element:

```
var matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(getComputedStyle($('#el')[0]).webkitTransform)
```

where `$('#el')` is your element.

then `matrix.a` and `matrix.d` should give relevant scaling factors. After that, simply use `$('#el').width()*matrix.a` and `$('#el').height()*matrix.d` respectively

Answer (score 0):

try `outerHeight()`, `outerWidth()`, `outerHeight(true)`, `outerWidth(true)`

also try giving your browser a break before you measure by scheduling your code with  `setTimout(function() { /* do you measuring here */ }, 0);`